# How do I divide the number of users from 2 different pages in Google Data Studio, using Scorecards?

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio

**I want to divide 123 by 9.2k (to give a %).**

- 123 = number of users on first page.
- 9.2k = number of users that go to the second page after visiting the first pace.

I want to calculate % of people going from first to second page.

Both data is from Google Analytics number of users.

Screenshot of Data Studio:

[image: Screenshot of Data Studio]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way that it can be achieved by selecting both Scorecards, then right clicking either Scorecard to Blend data and create a [Ratio Metric](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9457859):

1. <kbd>Left Click</kbd> on **Scorecard 1** (123 Users);
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Left Click</kbd> (on a Windows device, for a Mac use <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Left Click</kbd>) on **Scorecard 2** (9,200 Users);
3. With both [Scorecards](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7193479) selected, <kbd>Right Click</kbd> on either Scorecard and select **Blend data** from the drop down to create a new Scorecard, a Ratio Metric.

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/1d018de5-c84e-442a-8e88-9252f6322888) (Embedded [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pU6FlYaJ9vsUpC17G4VxogELZRNDzRcBo_PmYtDrLe8/edit?usp=sharing) Data Source) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]